# How can we transfer vector properties from one quantity to another?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, vectors

I am reading chapter "Moving Charges and Magnetism" in NCERT book. In the part talking about the force on a current-carrying wire in a uniform magnetic field, I read this strange transformation of vectors. I have highlighted the relevant parts.

> [image: 1]

***Can someone explain how and why did that happen?***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can length be a vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/325895/how-can-length-be-a-vector)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero isn't my question more about the transfer of vectors ?

Comment: There is no such thing as “transfer of vectors” and that phraseology is misleading.  It so happens that $I d\vec \ell$ is defined to have the vector part over the line element rather than the current element, whereas for other geometries the vector part is on the current element, as per https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/325898/36194

Comment: A very poorly worded presentation.

Answer (score 0):

$nq$ is the density of moving charges $\rho$. So, $$\mathbf j = \rho \frac{\mathbf{dx}}{dt}$$
If the density of current is constant over a straight wire:
$$\mathbf j = \rho \frac{\mathbf{\Delta x}}{\Delta t}$$
Naming I as $$I = \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t} = \frac{\rho lA}{\Delta t}$$

and $\mathbf l = \mathbf{\Delta x}$, we get the final expression.

Answer (score 0):

The (j) is a unit vector indicating a direction (in an xyz coordinate system). The (l) is a length which has a magnitude.  Assuming (l) is in the direction of (j), when you put them together you get a vector with a magnitude and direction.

Comment: how is **j** a unit vector ? Isn't it the current density vector ?

Comment: My mistake, but (j) is parallel to (l), so they do share the same direction.