# Understanding if possibly current density can be made scalar by changing the current definition?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge, vectors

- In the accepted answer to this question : [Why does current density have a direction and not current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156251/312538)

> I understand the need for current density to be vector, but I am now curious if the definition of current is changed and made to be the flow of charge from a **perpendicular surface** / charge passing through a **perpendicular surface** then in the accepted answer, we will not have a confusion of when to use $A$ and when to use $A cos \theta$ for area, and so then current density would be a scalar?, is this right, or would something else be a problem here now?

Comment: You're asking if the $\vec{j}$ in $\nabla\cdot\vec{j}+\dot{\rho}=0$ admits a scalar counterpart. Why would it? You may be confusing the respective roles of $\vec{j},\,\rho$, the latter being a scalar.